# Ruby: Accessing caller in method chain

Tags: ruby, method-chaining

I am trying to write an Or helper (based upon [Not Method by Jay Fields](http://blog.jayfields.com/2007/08/ruby-adding-not-method-for-readability.html)). What I am trying to achieve is:

```
s = ""
s.nil?             # false
s.empty?           # true
s.nil? || s.empty? # true
s.nil?.or.empty?   # should == true
```

I can access the result of `nil?` but not what the input to `nil?` was.

I get:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `empty?' for false:FalseClass
```

Is this even possible?

**Note:** this needs to be native ruby **not** rails!

Comment: I think I am done,please look at the answer and comment if any confusion you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot achieve this.

The return value of `s.nil?` is either `true` or `false`, which are the only instances of `TrueClass` and `FalseClass`, respectively. You cannot create other instances of the two classes. So you cannot monkey patch `TrueClass` or `FalseClass` to remember the context `s`. You can define singleton method `or` on `true` and `false`, however, it knows nothing about `s` so you cannot chain another predicate `empty?`.

```rb
def true.or other
  true
end

def false.or other
  other
end
```

You can write `s.nil?.or(s.empty?)` with the two helper method defined.

Another thought is to return a customized object for all predicate (blabla?) methods, rather than `true` or `false`. However, in ruby, only `nil` and `false` yield false, any other stuffs yield true. You instance of the customized object will always be true, which will break all those predicate methods.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
p RUBY_VERSION
p s = ""
p s.nil?             
p s.empty?           
p s.nil? || s.empty? 
p (s.nil? or s.empty?)
```

*Output:*

```
"2.0.0"
""
false
true
true
true
```

*Explanation:*

```
s.nil?
#=> false

s.nil?.or.empty?
#NoMethodError: undefined method `or' for false:FalseClass
#        from (irb):5
#        from C:/Ruby200/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

The above error because of `s.nil?` gives `false` and `false` is an instance of `FalseClass`, and this class don't have `or` method any. so actual fix is as above I have shown.

***EDIT***:

```
p RUBY_VERSION
class Object

alias :oldnil :nil?

    def nil?
    @@x = self
    oldnil
    end
end

class FalseClass
    def or
    empty?
    end

    def empty?
    @@x.empty?
    end
end

class TrueClass
    def or
    empty?
    end

    def empty?
    @@x.empty?
    end
end

s = ""
p s.nil?
p s.empty?
p s.nil? || s.empty?
p s.nil?.or.empty?
```

*Output:*

```
"2.0.0"
false
true
true
true
```

Comment: This works just for this particular combination of conditions. I think jamlen is interested in a more general solution. Besides, it is not thread-safe.